# Django: Show downloadable custom log file

Tags: python, django

I have a small Django Project, where the user can uplaod a csv file which is parsed to the Database.
If there are some formating issues detected during the processing I write them into a `pd.DataFrame` and want to show them to the user afterwards, so they know which lines of the csv could not be processed correctly.

I thought about a few ways to do this.
I could create a custom model only for the log, but I want the user to be able to download the log, which is why I would prefer to save the Log to a csv and show a download Link as well as the content of the Log, but I don't know how to do it or if there is a better way?

My Code looks something like this:

```
class ListVerifyView(ListView):
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        return context
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in request.POST.items():
            try:
                col_dict[v] = int(k)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        ...
        error_log = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Chemical', 'Error'])
        ...
        if not error_log.empty:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING, 'Some ERRORS occurred during import!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('show_error'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
```

I thought about saving the Log as a `models.FileField` and pass the `pk` to `reverse_lazy('show_error')` but I don't know how to save the `df.to_csvfile` to my `MEDIA_ROOT`

Thanks in advance.
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

If your log data is String, you may use [ContentFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) wrapper, initialize it with log string and assign it to your model instance's `models.FileField`, something like this:

```
your_log_mdl_instance.log_file_field = ContentFile(df.to_csv,name='error.log')
your_log_mdl_instance.save()
```

Or if you have csv file already exported, you may use [File](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/file/#the-file-class) wrapper, like this:

```
with File(open('/path/to/exported_file.cvs','rb'),name='error.log'):
    your_log_mdl_instance.log_file_field = f
    your_log_mdl_instance.save()
```